# Where clause in Dynamic Pivot SQL using Dates in Date Column

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot, where-clause

I use the WHERE clause in a sql pivot and it works:

```
SELECT Customer AS [Currency Per Customer], [USD], [EUR], [RUR], [CHF], [GBP]
FROM

(SELECT Customer, Amount, Currency
FROM Alpha.dbo.Beta
WHERE Date between '2010-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
)
x PIVOT
(
SUM(Amount)
FOR Currency IN ([USD], [EUR], [RUR], [CHF], [GBP])
) AS PivotTable

ORDER BY Customer;
```

However when I try to do it in a dynamic pivot it says there is an incorrect syntax near 2010.  Where should I place this WHERE clause..? If I have it here it does not work properly.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(currency) 
        FROM Alpha.dbo.Beta
        WHERE Date Between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT Customer, ' + @cols + ' FROM
        (
            SELECT Customer, Amount, Currency
            FROM Alpha.dbo.Beta
    ) x
        PIVOT
        (
             SUM(Amount)
            for Currency in (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS pvt

    ORDER BY Customer; '


execute(@query)
```

Please help,

Thanks,
A

Comment: Please it in the subquery `x`, right after the from` clause.

Comment: Here it comes back with Incorrect syntax near '2010'.  What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT Customer, ' + @cols + ' FROM
        (
            SELECT Customer, Amount, Currency
            FROM Alpha.dbo.Beta
            WHERE Date between ''2010-01-01'' and ''2013-12-31''
    ) x
        PIVOT
        (
             SUM(Amount)
            for Currency in (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS pvt

    ORDER BY Customer; '
```

Alternatively, use `sp_executesql` and use arguments.  Something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@start date, @end date', @start = '2010-01-01', @end = '2013-12-31'
```

Then the `where` would look like:

```
            WHERE Date between @start and @end
```

Comment: That did it Gordon... So simple when you know how :D  Thanks vmuch!

Comment: By the way, I do recommend `sp_executesql` to pass parameters in and out of dynamic SQL.  However, it won't work for `@cols` -- that has to be done the way you are doing it.

Comment: Why is it necessary to have two single apostrophes when 1 is sufficient if you don't use dynamic pivots.  Also I am using an @Date variable as I am using this code in a c# application but cannot get it to run as it still says of have incorrect syntex when i use apostrophes... eg.'@Date'and da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker4.Text;  How do I get it to accept the variable in c#?

Comment: In some environments, you use double apostrophes to generate one apostrophe *inside* a string.  As for the incorrect syntax, perhaps you should ask another question and post the C# code there.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315546/c-sharp-adding-a-variable-in-a-sql-dynamic-pivot-string