# c# adding a variable in a SQL dynamic pivot string

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datagridview, dynamic-pivot

I am trying to show the results of a dynamic pivot in a c# datagridview.  So far I have got the following code but I am stumped as how to incorporate the @Date variable in the @query string.  What am I missing here?  The code works fine with hard coded dates and as it is returns Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@Date'.  Please help,

Thanks,
A

```
da2.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                                    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +          QUOTENAME(currency) 
FROM Alpha.dbo.Beta 

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT Customer, ' + @cols + ' FROM
(
SELECT 
Customer, Amount, Currency
FROM Alpha.dbo.Beta
WHERE Date Between ''2010-01-01'' and '@Date' ----PROBLEM AREA----
) x
PIVOT
(
SUM(Amount)
for Currency in (' + @cols + ')
) AS pvt
ORDER BY Customer; '

execute(@query)", MyConnection);



da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker4.Text;
ds2.Clear();
da2.Fill(ds2);
```

Comment: What about just replacing in the string as text `". . ".THEDATE." . . ."`?

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code as:

```
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = dateTimePicker4.Text;
```

Also, use `stored procedure` instead the query.

Comment: It is a problem with the @Date being a variable in the substring.  how to overcome this?

Comment: Figured it out.  Basically you cannot use datetime in the @query.  you need to convert the parameters to varchar.

I used this and it works fine now:-
    
    WHERE Date Between ''2010-01-01'' and '''+ convert(varchar,    @Date) + '''

Comment: It is wrong way. Easy way to create SP. But you can also use `sp_executesql` instead of `execute(@query)` which can take parameters.